# Prove that $(v^Tx)^2-(u^Tx)^2 < 1-(u^Tv)^2$ for any unit vectors $u$, $v$, $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, metric-spaces, spherical-geometry

Let $u,v,x \in \mathbb R^d$ be three unit vectors. I found a very complicated proof that $(v^Tx)^2-(u^Tx)^2 \leq 1-(u^Tv)^2$.
That is $\lVert uu^T-vv^T\rVert^2_2 = 1-(u^Tv)^2$, or that $f(v,x)\leq f(v,u)+f(u,x)$ where $f(v,u)=1-(v^Tu)^2$ is the squared sine of the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Is there a one-liner proof?

Say, using the (spherical?) law of cosines or the Haversine formula? Induced norm for positive semi-definite matrices?

Edit: Thank you all for the quick answers. I am confused by the counter examples. I tried to cite Lemma 27 in a paper (I think from STOC'15):
https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05225
The eigenvalue of $||uu^T-vv^T||_2$ seems to be correct by
[How to find the eigenvalues of $xx^T-yy^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913336/how-to-find-the-eigenvalues-of-x-xt-y-yt)

Edit 2: I assumed that all the conjectures in the question are equivalent but maybe I was wrong. I took the Schur Decomposition $USU^T$ of $uu^T-vv^T$ to get $\max_{||x||=1} ||(uu^T-vv^T)x||^2=||USU^Tx||^2=S_{1,1}^2$ and assumed it is the same $\max_{||x||=1} |x^T(uu^T-vv^T)x|^2=|x^TUSU^Tx|=S_{1,1}^2$. Then I noticed that $|x^T(uu^T-vv^T)x|^2=|(x^Tu)^2-(v^Tx)|$. Not sure what went wrong.

Summary: As GH from Mo noted below, I forgot a squared root in the right hand side and the statement is wrong. Hope to get your help also in the fixed version [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417022/prove-that-vtx2%E2%88%92utx2-leq-sqrt1%E2%88%92utv2-for-any-unit-vectors-u-v)

Comment: An equivalent formulation:  $\langle v, x\rangle^2 + \langle u, v\rangle^2 \le \langle u, u\rangle^2 + \langle u, x\rangle^2$.

Comment: Just to check something: The claim is that the square of the sine ($f$) satisfies the triangle inequality. But for very tiny angles between $u, v, w$ then the sine of those angles is roughly Euclidean distance, and the square of Euclidean distance violates the triangle inequality. So it's surprising that this equation would hold for tiny angles. Have you checked cases like  $u = (0, \epsilon, \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2})$, $v = (0, 0, 1)$, and $x = (0,-\epsilon, \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2})$ ? Some quick algebra indicates this might be problematic when $\epsilon$ is tiny, but I may be getting confused.

Comment: Indeed, with @MartinM.W.'s [example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414965/prove-that-vtx2-utx2-1-utv2-for-any-unit-vectors-u-v-x#comment1064139_414965), I find that $(1 - \langle u, v\rangle^2) - (\langle v, x\rangle^2 - \langle u, x\rangle^2)$ equals $2\epsilon^2(2\epsilon^2 - 1)$, which, for $\epsilon = 1/2$ (to pick a random example), gives $-1/4$, contrary to your conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality as stated is false, but it is true that
$$\langle v,x\rangle^2+\langle v,u\rangle^2\leq 1+|\langle x,u\rangle|.$$
Moreover, the right-hand side is optimal in the sense that it is the maximum of the left-hand side over the unit vectors $v$. More generally, if $u_1,\dots,u_R$ are any vectors in a Hilbert space, then
$$\max_{\langle v,v\rangle=1}\sum_{r=1}^R|\langle v,u_r\rangle|^2$$
equals the largest eigenvalue of the Gram matrix $(\langle u_s,u_t\rangle)_{1\leq s,t\leq R}$. For details, see [these notes](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Egharcos/bombieri-halasz-montgomery.pdf) on the Bombieri-Halász-Montgomery inequality.

Comment: Thanks! Do you agree with the original equality $||uu^T-vv^T||^2_2=1-(u^Tv)^2$? If yes, can we use a similar technique to prove it?

Comment: @QueenMath - Do you mean $\|uu^T - vv^T\|_2^2 = 2 - 2(u^Tv)^2$? That equality follows immediately from the definition of the Frobenius norm (by subscript $2$, do you mean the Frobenius norm, aka the Schatten 2-norm?).

Comment: @QueenMath Please ask separate questions in a separate post. I answered your question. Your conjecture is false. I fixed it and generalized it to an arbitrary number of vectors.

Comment: ||A||_2 in my question is the largest eigenvalue of a matrix, $\max_x ||Ax||_2/||x||$ where $A=uu^T-vv^T$ is a matrix. Not the Frobenius norm (sum of squared entries) of $A$.

Comment: Thanks again, but I did not meant to ask a new question. I was referring to the conjecture $||uu^T-vv^T||^2_2=1-(u^Tv)^2$ in the question.

Comment: @QueenMath Your question (as in the title) was about an inequality that is false. This means that whatever complicated proof you had, it was incorrect. Now your identity has little to do with your inequality. Your confusion seems to be two-fold. First, you seem to confuse the Frobenius norm and the $L^2$-norm of a matrix. In your previous remark, you talk about the $L^2$-norm of $A$. The square of this norm is the maximum of $\|A x\|^2=x^TA^TAx$ over the unit vectors $x$, and it has little to do with the maximum of $(v^Tx)^2-(u^Tx)^2$ over the unit vectors $x$.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but some clarifications are still needed: 1) The long proof is from the famous cited paper in the question. 2) I was always referring to L_2 and not Frobenius norm of a matrix, including when writing $||uu^T-vv^T||^2_2$ above. Note that $uu^T$ is a matrix, not a vector. 3) In the second edit I explained the connection between the title and $||uu^T=vv^T||_2$. I assume it is correct, unlike the title, but still do not understand where is the bug in the reduction...

Comment: @QueenMath I think what went wrong is that you forgot the square in the end. The square of the largest eigenvalue is not the maximum of $|(x^Tu)^2-(v^Tx)^2|$, but the maximum of $|(x^Tu)^2-(v^Tx)^2|^2$.